Ask Mathematica to prioritize writing an expression in terms of another
I have an old reference text with tables of solid spherical harmonics expressed in cartesian coordinates. (Edit: Here's a digital version of said table, for the curious.) In an attempt to replicate this table, I wrote a function in Mathematica v 13 which uses the built-in SphericalHarmonic and LegendreP functions and then converts to cartesian coordinates. It seems to work well with just spot checking against these reference tables, however... The author prioritized writing all functions in terms of $r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$ (note $r,x,y,z>0$ and real) so my results don't always visually match. A quick application of Solve proves they're mathematically the same, but I'm wondering:
Is there a way to ask Mathematica to prioritize writing these expressions in terms of r? I.e. write each of the left expressions as the right.
$-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{5}{\pi }} \left(x^2+y^2-2 z^2\right)}{4 r^2} = -\frac{\sqrt{\frac{5}{\pi }} \left(r^2-3 z^2\right)}{4 r^2}$
$\frac{3 \left(3 x^4+6 x^2 \left(y^2-4 z^2\right)+3 y^4-24 y^2 z^2+8 z^4\right)}{16 \sqrt{\pi } r^4} = \frac{3(35z^4-30z^2r^2+3r^4)}{16 \sqrt{\pi } r^4} $
$-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{13}{\pi }} \left(5 x^6+15 x^4 \left(y^2-6 z^2\right)+15 x^2 \left(y^4-12 y^2 z^2+8 z^4\right)+5 y^6-90 y^4 z^2+120 y^2 z^4-16
   z^6\right)}{32 r^6} = -\frac{\sqrt{\frac{13}{\pi }} (231z^6-315z^4r^2+105z^2r^4-5r^6)}{64 r^6}$
For simple cases, this is pretty easy. For example, I have already been able to make the conversion
$-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{5}{\pi }} \left(x^2+y^2-2 z^2\right)}{4 \left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)}=-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{5}{\pi }} \left(x^2+y^2-2 z^2\right)}{4 r^2}$ and similar in all the expressions above using /. x^2 + y^2 + z^2 -> r^2. But taking that expression all the way to the desired final result is not so simple.
Perhaps pure functions could help? I'm unsure how to ask Mathematica to prioritize something like that, though, because the step to go, e.g., $(x^2+y^2-2 z^2)=(x^2+y^2-3 z^2+z^2)$ is an expansion that I then need to be followed by a grouping of terms to $(x^2+y^2+z^2-3 z^2)$ which then enables replacement (and in some cases, further simplification) to achieve an end result like $(r^2-3 z^2)$. Expand -> Collect -> Some math or rules -> Replace -> Simplify Such a process may not always work. Curious if anyone can find a way to programmatically achieve this. I'll post, too, if I discover an answer.
Edit
For those asking for raw code, here are the example equations in input form rather than TeX.
ex1=-((Sqrt[5/Pi]*(x^2 + y^2 - 2*z^2))/(4*r^2))
ex2=(3*(3*x^4 + 3*y^4 - 24*y^2*z^2 + 8*z^4 + 6*x^2*(y^2 - 4*z^2)))/(16*Sqrt[Pi]*r^4)
ex3=-((Sqrt[13/Pi]*(5*x^6 + 5*y^6 - 90*y^4*z^2 + 120*y^2*z^4 - 16*z^6 + 15*x^4*(y^2 - 6*z^2) + 15*x^2*(y^4 - 12*y^2*z^2 + 8*z^4)))/(32*r^6))

These are just examples; I'm really curious about having Mathematica prioritize writing expressions in terms of another expression. Sort of like u-substitution but allowing for less than complete replacement.
Another common example in my field would be like:
ex4=Exp[(h*\[Omega])/(k*T)]

$e^{\frac{h \omega }{k T}}=e^{s \omega }$ with $s=\frac{h}{k T}$ which is again trivial using Replace.  This comes from statistical thermodynamics, where such terms usually show up in more complex expressions like:
ex5=((h*\[Omega])/T)^2*(1/k)*(Exp[(h*\[Omega])/(k*T)]/(Exp[(h*\[Omega])/(k*T)] - 1)^2)

$(\frac{h\omega}{T})^2*\frac{1}{k}*\frac{e^{\frac{h\omega}{kT}}}{(e^{\frac{h\omega}{kT}}-1)^2}$ which, if one recognizes that the $k$ can be pulled inside the first term, may be rewritten as $(\frac{h\omega}{kT})^2*k*\frac{e^{\frac{h\omega}{kT}}}{(e^{\frac{h\omega}{kT}}-1)^2}$ and finally $(s*\omega)^2*k*\frac{e^{s*\omega}}{(e^{s*\omega}-1)^2}$. Replace doesn't cut it in this case.
Obviously humans can recognize and do these steps, but can Mathematica?

People here generally like users to post code as copyable Mathematica code as well as images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site, helpful

Use the resource function AlgebraicReplace. Example:`In[21]:=
e1 = 3 (3 x^4 + 6 x^2 (y^2 [Minus] 4 z^2) + 3 y^4 [Minus]
24 y^2 z^2 + 8 z^4)/(16 [Pi]*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2);
In[22]:=
ResourceFunction["AlgebraicReplace"][e1, (x^2 + y^2 + z^2), r^2]
Out[22]= (9 r^4 - 90 r^2 z^2 + 105 z^4)/(16 [Pi] r^4)`

@DanielLichtblau nice and very useful function, I did not know there was such a thing. This should be builtin function !

@Nasser Thanks. Maybe some day...

@DanielLichtblau that's a good one! Adding to my favorites list. Does work for my initial set of examples, although notably it un-simplifies the factors (multiplies ones outside the parentheses all the way through). Could be beneficial in that way compared to Replace. However, it doesn't work for ex4=Exp[(h*\[Omega])/(k*T)].

This works:`In[29]:= ex4 = Exp[(h*[Omega])/(kT)];
ResourceFunction["AlgebraicReplace"][ex4,
h/(kT), s, {h, k, T, [Omega]}]
Out[30]= E^(s [Omega])` The hitch is that the variables need to be put there explicitly. I'll give some thought to improving on that part.

@DanielLichtblau Would you post an answer then and I'll accept it?

I have submitted an update to AlgebraicReplace that should (usually) handle the issue with determining what are the variables.

There is a resource function called AlgebraicReplace that is intended for this sort of task. The syntax is like so:
ResourceFunction["AlgebraicReplace"][expression, subexpression(s), replacementname(s), optionalvariablelist]

Here is one of the examples.
ee = 3*(3*x^4 + 6*x^2*(y^2 - 4*z^2) + 3*y^4 - 24*y^2*z^2 + 8*z^4)/
  (16*Sqrt[Pi]*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2);
ResourceFunction["AlgebraicReplace"][ee, (x^2 + y^2 + z^2), r^2]

(* Out[4]= (9 r^4 - 90 r^2 z^2 + 105 z^4)/(16 Sqrt[\[Pi]] r^4) *)

A caveat is that if the input is not explicitly polynomial one might need to indicate with an optional fourth argument what are the variables. The example below will not work without that data.
ex4 = Exp[(h*omega)/(k*T)];
ResourceFunction["AlgebraicReplace"][ex4, h/(k*T), s, {h, k, T, omega}]

(* Out[8]= E^(omega s) *)


Please post plain text code as my home made image->Mathematica code translator function is still not perfect.
One possible way is
e1 = -Sqrt[5/Pi]*(x^2 + y^2 - 2*z^2)/(4*r^2)
e1 /. x -> Sqrt[r^2 - (y^2 + z^2)]


e2 = 3*(3*x^4 + 6*x^2*(y^2 - 4*z^2) + 3*y^4 - 24*y^2*z^2 + 8*z^4)/(16*     Sqrt[Pi]*r^4)
e2 /. x -> Sqrt[r^2 - (y^2 + z^2)] // Simplify


etc..

This replacement does indeed work for this specific case, so thanks! Need to think more about whether it answers my more general question.

I guess the issue with this is that in order to use Replace alone, I'd need to know that the expression is in the "wrong" format. But for a different value of n or m in LegendreP[n,m,x] I might get an answer which is already in the "right" format, and Replace would then give the wrong answer. Such as ex6=-((Sqrt[3/Pi]*x)/(2*r))
